# How is the event-loop implemented in node.js?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

If node simply has two threads, one to execute the main code and the other for all the callbacks, then blocking can still occur if the callbacks are resource/time intensive.

Say you have 100,000 concurrent users and each client request to the node app runs a complicated and time consuming database query, (assuming no caching is done) will the later users experience blocking when waiting for the query to return?

```
function onRequest(request, response) {
  //hypothetical database call
  database.query("SELECT * FROM hugetable", function(data) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("database result: " + data);
    response.end();
  });      
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

If each callback can run on its own thread, then this is a non-issue. But if all the callbacks  run on a single separate dedicated thread then node doesn't really help us much in such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this good article: http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/
There is no multiple threads, only one that executes your node.js logic. (Behind the scenes I/O should not be considered for application logic)

Requests to database are async as well - all you do, is put query in queue for transfer to db socket, then everything else happens behind the scenes and it will callback back only when there is response from database comes, so there is no blocking from application logic.